# Android: app:layout_constrainedHeight cuts last line of text in the text view

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a TextView in the ConstraintLayout with large text, but the last line is not visible. If I remove `app:layoutthen_constrainedHeight` it becomes visible, but TextView becomes as high as the screen itself (that's why I've added `app:layoutthen_constrainedHeight` in the first place)

Does anyone faced such issue? What can be done with it? In the example below last chars "3 4" should be on the second line, but they are not displayed.
Screenshot:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:background="@color/red"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/image_2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_2"
        tools:text="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/image_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_1"
        tools:text="end"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in the ConstraintLayout versions 1.1.3 up to 2.0.0-beta1
Here's task in the bag tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132314169

It will be fixed in 2.0.0-beta2

Answer (score 0):

try this, maybe worded:

```
android:minLines="2"
```

so it is forced to be at least 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you need to layout_height a value as it's away too long, so you need to be more specific :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image_1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/image_2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_2"
    tools:text="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
              6"
    />
```

Comment: I need it to be wrap content as the different length of content is expected, so fixed height is not the option unfortunately